# Angular 2 iso date format

Tags: angular

How can I format the ISO date into correct format? The date format return from the server side is like: 2016-12-28T11:44:00Z.

Here is my html:

```
<tr *ngFor="#ticket of tickets">
   <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.subject}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.status}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.updated_at}}</td>
    <td><a [routerLink]="['SingleTicket', {'id': ticket.id}]" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</a></td>
</tr>
```

And here is the ticket interface.

```
export interface Ticket {
    id: number,
    subject: string,
    description: string,
    status: string,
    submitter: number,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
}
```

Comment: have you tried with pipe ? like | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I tried, but Invalid argument '2016-12-28T11:44:00Z' for pipe 'DatePipe

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried with PIPE? .. (old Angular 1 filter) .. something like:

```
<td>{{ticket.created_at | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried pipe, Invalid argument '2016-12-28T11:44:00Z' for pipe 'DatePipe

Comment: also with something like: | date:'fullDate'

Comment: the way you suggest

Comment: try with {{ticket.created_at | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }} or with {{ticket.created_at | date:'fullDate' }}

Comment: tried, EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '2016-12-28T11:44:00Z' for pipe 'DatePipe' in [{{ticket.created_at | date: 'fullDate'}

Comment: thnx .. happy it helped you!!

Answer (score 2):

`<td>{{ticket.created_at | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>`

you can add pipe and filter the format

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) by `npm install moment --save` and

```
const moment = require('moment')    
formatedDate = moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07", moment.ISO_8601);
```

You can also choose other formats

```
moment('2016-12-28T11:44:00Z').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // December 30th 2016, 9:56:04 am
moment('2016-12-28T11:44:00Z').format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment('2016-12-28T11:44:00Z').format("MMM Do YY");               // Dec 30th 16
moment('2016-12-28T11:44:00Z').format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `moment.js`:

```
<tr *ngFor="#ticket of tickets">
  <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.subject}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.status}}</td>
  <td>{{formatDateTime(ticket.created_at)}}</td>
  <td>{{formatDateTime(ticket.updated_at)}}</td>
  <td><a [routerLink]="['SingleTicket', {'id': ticket.id}]" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</a></td>
</tr>
```

In `controller`:

```
formatDateTime(date: Date): string {
    if (!date) {
        return '';
    }

    return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
}
```

It is working for me, Hope will work for you also.

Comment: @Avensh hi, I am using angular 2, looks like your way is for angular1

Comment: I updated code. and this is also working fine in angular 2.0. I am using version `"moment": "=2.17.1"` with webpack.

Comment: @Avensh hi, after install moment, how can I import it? import {moment} from 'moment/moment'; not working

Comment: use this: `import * as moment from 'moment';` and `'node_modules'` should be added `modulesDirectories` which I think will be already added.